# JS variable value is wrong outside function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Before you say "The variable must be declared globally, and not inside the function", it already is .

In a Node/Express setup I retrieve the value of a the variable `loggedIn` from the BE. This is 1 if the user is logged in, and 0 if the user is not. The value should determine which header is loaded.

This is the code, let's say user A is logged in:

```
    let loggedIn = 0 // VALUE IS DECLARED OUTSIDE THE FUNCTION LIKE IT SHOULD BE

    async function checkLoggedIn () { // THE FUNCTION TO CHECK IS USER IS LOGGED IN
        const res = await fetch('users/authenticate')
        const loggedInString = await res.json()
        loggedIn = parseInt(loggedInString)
        console.log(loggedIn) // THIS LOGS OUT '1' LIKE IT SHOULD BECAUSE USER A IS LOGGED IN
    }

    checkLoggedIn() // WE RUN THE FUNCTION

    console.log(loggedIn) // THIS LOGS OUT '0' EVEN THOUGH USER A IS LOGGED IN
```

For the life of me, I can't figure out why the value of `loggedIn` is 0 outside the function.

One thing to note is that the log first logs out the value of `loggedIn` outside the function (i.e. the second instance in the code). Why is that? The function is being called before the `console.log(loggedIn)` outside the function is run.

This is what the browser logs out when the code is run:

```
0 (index):12 // VALUE OUTSIDE THE FUNCTION
1 (index):7 // VALUE INSIDE THE FUNCTION
```

Line 12 is logged out before line 7, which I don't understand.

I am sure there is a simple explanation, but I just don't get it.

Comment: `checkLoggedIn()` is async, so your `loggedIn = 1` assignment hasn't run by the time it hits the 2nd `console.log()`. You'll need to `await` the `checkLoggedIn()` call, or chain a `.then` to run some code afterward. e.g. `await checkLoggedIn(); console.log(loggedIn) // 1` or `checkLoggedIn().then(() => { console.log(loggedIn) });

Comment: @romellem, Thanks! I (wrongly) assumed that the `await` inside the function would halt the execution of the code until a response was received and stored. I'll need to study this a bit more.